# iPhone - Cache name for NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: iphone, caching, core-data

G'day Folks

My CoreData driven app has a number of views of data from the same store & all using an NSFetchedResultsController. Currently they all have the same name for the NSFetchedResultsController cache, "Root". Users of my app can, & probably will, jump indiscriminately between views. Would it be better for user experience if I gave the cache for each NSFetchedResultsController a unique name?

TIA, Pedro :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Providing a different cache name for different fetches is advisable and will help with performance.

From Apple documentation at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008227-CH1-SW24

> If you have multiple fetched results
>   controllers with different
>   configurations (different sort
>   descriptors and so on), you must give
>   each a different cache name.

Cheers,
Rog

Comment: Thanks Rog, I thought that was the case & hadn't been able to find it in the Apple docs (which are great if you manage to find what you're looking for). Fortunately it's not going to be a difficult change for me to make. Cheers, Pedro :)