# NSFetchedResultsController with NSPredicate not updating

Tags: core-data, ios, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nspredicate

I fetch data from a Core Data-base and present them in a `UITableView`. I use a `NSFetchedResultController` to fetch the data. I want the user to be able to search in the database, and to do that I use a `NSPredicate`.

The data is presented in the `UITableView` and everything works well until I set the `NSPredicate` to the `NSFetchedResultController`.

I use this in the `ViewDidLoad` method:

```
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
fetchedResultsController_ = nil;

NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);
}
```

and when the user has entered a text from the `UITextField`, that text will go to the new `NSPredicate`.

This is done when the search starts:

```
NSPredicate *pred = nil;
pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(Designation BEGINSWITH '22')"];
[fetchedResultsController_.fetchRequest setPredicate:pred];

NSError *error = nil;
if (![[self fetchedResultsController] performFetch:&error]) {
    NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
    exit(-1);
}

[tView reloadData];
```

Right now I use `@"(Designation BEGINSWITH '22')"` for testing only.

This is my NSFetchedResultsController:

```
    - (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController_ != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController_;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Product" inManagedObjectContext:importContext];//self.managedObjectContext
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Designation" ascending:NO];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:importContext sectionNameKeyPath:nil cacheName:@"Root"]; //self.managedObjectContext

    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    return fetchedResultsController_;
}
```

The problem is that the fetched data stays the same, no matter how or if I set a predicate. If I would set a predicate in the `viewDidLoad` it would work, but then I wouldn't be able to get new results if I'd tried that again. I use an "`importContext`" for a batch-import of my CoreData.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE:
Ok, here is what I found out. I have an `importContext` where I make a batch-import. And for the `fetchController` I use `self.managedObjectContext`. That's why it doesn't work, so I have to make `self.managedObjectContext` have the same stuff as my `importContext` somehow...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a cache (@"Root")… Try setting it to nil, this could prevent crashes. You should not cache FetchedResultsControllers meant to be Predicated.

Comment: Thank you! I'm back from the holiday and I finally got it to work, thanks to you! Also, for those with similar problem, I can say that I import the content to my Core Data in a different thread and use NSNotification. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

Even better than setting the cache to `nil` is giving it a unique name. After posting this question
[iPhone - Cache name for NSFetchedResultsController](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4295474/iphone-cache-name-for-nsfetchedresultscontroller)
I added a function to generate UUIDs as my cache names.