# Why does my NSFetchedResultsController delegate stop firing when I add an NSPredicate?

Tags: ios, ios5, nspredicate, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I have an `NSFetchedResultsController` displaying "places" in a table view, but when I update the set of places that should be displayed in another view controller, my FRC does not update the table view.

That's the general problem.  My specific case seems to revolve around the `NSPredicate` backing my FRC, because when I remove the `NSPredicate` (and just get *all* places), everything works fine.

My query is

```
@"ANY photos.isFavorite == %@", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
```

*places* have a one-to-many relationship with *photos* (I am working through CS193P).  Perhaps my FRC is not set up to observe changes in a related table or something?

A bit of additional information about my situation:

- My Core Data updates and queries seem okay, as my "places" table is always correct when I first load the application.
- My FRC *does* update rows that are already present at application load.  It just won't insert new rows/sections at runtime.
- I am only using a single MOC.
- [My `sectionNameKeyPath` is *not* set to a transient attribute.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4637744/didchangesection-nsfetchedresultscontroller-delegate-method-not-being-called)
- [My `cacheName` is set to nil.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4503616/nsfetchedresultscontroller-with-nspredicate-not-updating)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if it's your case but I'll post anyway. Maybe it could be a valid workaround.

[NSFetchedResultsController pitfall](http://www.mlsite.net/blog/?p=825)

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, that was it.  For the record, FRC doesn't pick up changes on entities other than those of the type it is meant to fetch.  The workaround is to manually "dirty" the relevant entity (in my case, the relevant *place*) so FRC will see the change.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

- Did you try testing a simpler predicate, for example using a photo one-to-one relationship instead of photos?
- "my FRC does not update the table view" - Are you using -controllerDidChangeContent: ? Did you verify it is not getting called? I've seen that contrary to the documentation, calling reloadData on the tableView from within this method is unsafe, since the method may be called on a secondary rather than the main thread.
- Are you performing all operations related to the MOC on the same (main?) thread?

Comment: A simpler predicate does indeed work.  When I omit the predicate entirely or use a predicate that deals strictly with *places* (rather than prompting a join to *photos*), the table view is updated as I expect.  (To answer your other two questions: yes.)

Answer (score 0):

Try this predicate instead?

```
@"%@ IN photos.isFavorite", [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]
```